# PHPmyAdmin automatically adding ORDER BY to browse

Tags: phpmyadmin

A short time ago phpMyAdmin started adding an ORDER BY clause to a particular table whenever I browse it or even apply an SQL query. I can't figure out how to undo this.

If I type the following in the SQL editor:
**SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product = 'SERVICE'**

The query phpMyAdmin actually runs is. . .
**SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product = 'SERVICE' ORDER BY adjust DESC**

The column adjust doesn't even have an index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you hover over the column heading, you can see a menu displayed which lists several sorting options. It sounds like you may have inadvertently clicked or shift-clicked on a column header, so the solution is to `ctrl`-click or `alt`-click (or `shift`-`option`-click if you're on a Mac) to remove the `ORDER BY` clause.

[image: Mouseover menu]