# phpmyadmin disable default order by

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've setup phpmyadmin for a mysql db, and whenever I open mysql on a table, it does `SELECT * FROM db ORDER BY time ASC` by default, and because the db is somewhat large it takes ~10 seconds to load each time because of the ordering. How can I make phpmyadmin stop adding the ORDER BY when loading the page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPmyAdmin automatically adding ORDER BY to browse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809816/phpmyadmin-automatically-adding-order-by-to-browse)

Answer (score 6):

If you hover over the heading of the sorted column (`time`, in your case), you can get a tool tip with some help about sorting:

[image]

To remove it from the ORDER BY clause, you can hold in a modifier key while clicking on the heading: CTRL or ALT (on Windows and Linux, one or the other should work depending on your browser and configuration) or SHIFT+OPTION (on a Mac).

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/a/26037628/1834212

Comment: mucho mucho thanxs!

Comment: @Isaac Bennetch, I had the exact same scenario. Thank you!